# Jar doesn't work when it reads .csv

Tags: java, javafx, jar

I created simple project which program reads data from csv files and puts it into TableView. Program works great in netbeans but when I did clean and build and put jar and csv files to another folder program doesn't want to start, nothing happens, but when I remove csv files from folder jar is working but without any data in tableview (Its Obvious because program doesn't have any data to load). Here is my code to read the csv files:

```
class CSVeasyReader {

 private boolean IsFirstLineDescription;
     private FileReader reader;
 public ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


 public CSVeasyReader(FileReader reader, boolean IsFirstLineDescription) throws FileNotFoundException
 {
     this.IsFirstLineDescription = IsFirstLineDescription;
     this.reader = reader;
     addToList();
 }

 private void addToList() throws FileNotFoundException
 {
             BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(reader);
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(buff);
     if(IsFirstLineDescription == true)
     {
         scanner.nextLine();
         while(scanner.hasNextLine())
         {
             list.add(scanner.nextLine());
         }
     }
     else
     {
         while(scanner.hasNextLine())
         {
             list.add(scanner.nextLine());
         }
     }
     scanner.close();
 }
        void ReadEverything() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    CSVeasyReader MagazynpReader = new CSVeasyReader(new FileReader("Magazynp.csv"), true);
    CSVeasyReader MagazynwReader = new CSVeasyReader(new FileReader("Magazynw.csv"), true); 
    CSVeasyReader SlownikReader = new CSVeasyReader(new FileReader("Slownik.csv"), true);
    CSVeasyReader DostawcyReader = new CSVeasyReader(new FileReader("Dostawcy.csv"), true); 
    }
```

Its not my whole code of program but if You want I can give you all. Void ReadEverything() Is in another class: public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable.

Comment: An entry inside a .jar file is not an actual file.  You cannot use FileReader to read it.  Use `new InputStreamReader(CSVeasyReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/Magazynp.csv"))` instead.

Comment: But those .csv are not in .jar but in another folder.

Comment: If the jar-file is in another folder than your CSV-files, you are missing that folder-name. `new FileReader("Dostawcy.csv")` expects the csv-files in the same folder as the "current working folder", which might be the problem here. Try to launch your executable jar-file via `java -jar yourProject.jar` when being in the outcome-folder with the csv-files aside of it.